# "there is an error showing cannot use type range for int" error is showing in my CPLEX code

Tags: visual-studio, optimization, error-handling, cplex

```
range n=1..4;
int m[n]=[1,2,3,4];
int c[n]=[5,6,7,8];
float y[n];
dvar float x[n];
execute
{ y[n]=m[n]*x[n]+c[n];
  }
  minimize y[n];
  subject to
  {
    5<=x[n]<=20;
    
    }
```

This is the executed code.

Answer (score 0):

```
range n=1..4; 

int m[n]=[1,2,3,4]; 

int c[n]=[5,6,7,8]; 

dvar float y[n]; 

dvar float x[n]; 

//execute { y[n]=m[n]*x[n]+c[n]; } 

minimize sum(i in n)y[i]; 

subject to { 

forall(i in n) y[i]==m[i]*x[i]+c[i];

forall(i in n) 5<=x[i]<=20;  
}
```

works fine

and gives

```
y = [10
         16 22 28];
x = [5 5 5 5];
```